# Can we create a load test having different geographies user with Cloud-based load testing?

Tags: load-testing, performance-testing

I need to create a load test which should have users from USA , japan and few more countries.

Can I have a single loadtest where I can specify % number of user like 
USA -80% , JAPAN - 10% ,France -10%

How to make settings?

I am supposed to use cloud based load test setting from Visual studio.